# Using $args in nginx rewrite causing duplicate URL parameters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

In one of my location rules, I am trying to rewrite the URL as such:

```
rewrite ^ $topicredirecturi?$args permanent;
```

`$topicredirecturi` is calculated in a map file, mapping for example a URL such as

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit-group-inc/index.html
```

to

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit_group_inc/index.html
```

When I make my request with URL parameters such as:

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit-group-inc/index.html?rss=1
```

I get the following rewritten URL with duplicate params:

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit_group_inc/index.html?rss=1&rss=1
```

Similarly, the URL

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit-group-inc/index.html?rss=1&bob=2
```

gets rewritten to

```
http://www.topics.com/companies/cit_group_inc/index.html?rss=1&bob=2&rss=1&bob=2
```

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 19):

Nginx appends the query string automatically if there are other get parameters in the rewritten URL. If you're adding `$args` yourself you should add a `?` (question mark) at the end of the rewritten URL to avoid having duplicate parameters.

The correct way of doing a redirect with query string is this:

```
rewrite ^(...)$ /destination$is_args$args? [permanent|redirect];
```

where `$is_args` contains a `?` iff the query string is not empty, and `$args` is the query string itself; the question mark at the end requests to nginx to not add the query string again.